# Recover a MySQL InnoDB from ibdata1 that won't repair using innodb_force_recovery

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a MySQL database that we have manage to grab the raw files from a server with a fatal hardware failure. However, this failure seems to have occurred when the DB server was running.

As a result we have the ibdata1 file, the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and all of the .frm files.

innodb_force_recovery does not work from 1 to 6.

Are there any tools on the market or methods that we can use to recover these databases?

Thanks in advance

PS - backups have also failed for a different reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Percona data recovery toolkit](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/26/data-recovery-toolkit-for-innodb-version-01-released/)

Comment: From the documentation: `It is important to understand that these tools are not designed for connecting to a live database and recovering data from it. They work on an offline copy of the data, and it is not safe to use them on a copy that is in use by MySQL.`

Comment: Thank you - I am trying these and also in touch with Percona directly. Any other suggestions, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The long and the short of this is that percona's tools allow table by table recovery of your database.

What we managed to achieve was to get the server up and running again on the old HDD. Even though it went back into read only mode after a short period, that was enough for the db to repair enough of itself to be able to recover the data.